# VSTO C# expose ribbon events to other document level components

Tags: vsto

I have an a custom Excel Workbook using C# and VSTO.

Is there anyway for a worksheet to reference the ribbon and subscribe to events, or manipulate controls in the ribbon?

I haven't been able to find the syntax in Globals.Ribbons that will give me a handle to the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this same problem.  So far, no luck.  I'll be watching this thread!  The ribbon XML API seems to be how Office abstracts the ribbon and keeps you from having any direct access.